# Why does this SQL statement work the way it does?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been looking to find a good way to do a SQL query where I can have a where statement which, if left blank, will act like it wasn't there at all. I've found this, which seems to work quite well:

```
WHERE (Column = @value OR @value is null)
```

If I specify a value for @value, the search is filtered like I want. But if I pass in null, it's like saying @value can be anything. I like this. This is good. What I don't understand though is, why does this work like this?

Comment: `@value is null` is not  saying that value is 'anything'.  it's actually saying that @value is nothing.  Which is what you want in this case.  @value is either nothing (it can't compmared to anything) or it's something--then it can be compared to a specific @value.  Now why did that just sound like some kind of existentialist philosophy?  :-}

Comment: @DWright That was awesome  :-) . Discussions about null are challenging. Especially when comparing SQL null to the (somewhat) easier to understand null in C#/Java and other imperative(?) languages. Same name, different concept.

Comment: Another way of doing the same thing if you want: `WHERE Column = ISNULL(@value, Column)`

Comment: @MarkD I've found that doesn't work if the column contains any NULL values

Comment: Quite true - I forgot about that tbh :)

Comment: The execution plan for this query may well be sub optimal unless you use `OPTION RECOMPILE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If @value is null, your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (Column = @value OR @value is null)
```

reduces to

```
WHERE (Column = @value OR 1=1)
```

(This is similar to `if (Column == value || true)` in other common languages)

An OR conjunction is true if either of its operands (sides) are true: [SQL uses three valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)

```
+---------+------+---------+---------+
| A OR B  | TRUE | Unknown |  FALSE  |
+---------+------+---------+---------+
| TRUE    | TRUE | TRUE    | TRUE    |
| Unknown | TRUE | Unknown | Unknown |
| FALSE   | TRUE | Unknown | FALSE   |
+---------+------+---------+---------+
```

And so:

- If @value is null, the right side of your WHERE clause is true, so the entire conditional is true, and your WHERE clause will always be satisfied.
- If @value *isn't* null, then the right side of your WHERE clause is false, then whether the WHERE clause is satisfied depends on whether `Column = @value`.

Comment: It's been fun watching as you've slowly edited your answer to have all of this information and explanation

Comment: I discovered a batch of ASCII table generator websites just after I semi-laboriously typed in that truth table. I was tempted to edit again, but I had to stop at some point. :-)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: `Column = @value OR 1` will not work on SQL Server, 1 must be replaced by some condition. Please correct it or help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two cases:

1) @value is "something".

In this case, the second clause is always false, because "something" is never null. So all that effectively remains is `WHERE Column = @value`.

2) @value is null

In this case, the second clause is always false, because null never equals anything. So all that effectively remains is `WHERE @value is null` and @value is known to be null, so this is like `WHERE 1 = 1` and the whole WHERE is ignored. The database should be clever enough to figure this out before touching any data, so this should perform just like if there was no condition specified at all.

So what you have here, is a single SQL statement that can act like two, with an "optional WHERE". The advantage over two separate SQL statements for the two cases is that you don't need conditional logic in your application when building the SQL statement (which can get really hairy if there are more than one of these "toggles").